# How to remove the multiple lines in the file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

The `test.txt` file contains 3 lines:

```
STREET=main
PHONE=123
EMAIL=abc@xyz.com
```

To remove two lines with the `STREET` and `EMAIL` I run the `sed` twice in a row:

```
sed -i -- 's/STREET=.*//' test.txt
sed -i -- 's/EMAIL=.*//' test.txt
```

Instead of using the `sed` command twice I would rather remove both lines with a single `sed` command. How to do it?

Comment: Do you want to remove the lines or just make them empty?

Comment: `sed -e '/STREET=/d' -e '/EMAIL=/d'`

Comment: Unfortunately `sed -e '/STREET=/d' -e '/EMAIL=/d'` is not working for me.

Comment: @Cyrus It would be great if the lines could be removed instead of just making the empty. Please post you solution if you have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete (`d`) lines which contain `STREET=` or `EMAIL=`.

```
sed -i -- '/STREET=/d; /EMAIL=/d' file
```

Comment: It works well. But it leaves an extra empty line at end of the file.

Comment: There's something wrong with your file. Please add output of this to your question: `tail -n 1 file | hexdump -C`

Comment: `00000000  50 48 4f 4e 45 3d 31 32  33 0a                    |PHONE=123.|`

`0000000a`

Comment: There is only a `0a` left which represents the normal line end on Unix and Linux systems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -- 's/STREET=.*//;s/EMAIL=.*//' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The following sed one-liners show how to remove/empty the target lines:

### Empty the target lines:

```
kent$  sed 's/^\(EMAIL\|STREET\)=.*//' file

PHONE=123
```

### Remove the target lines:

```
kent$  sed '/^\(EMAIL\|STREET\)=/d' file
PHONE=123
```

Using pattern `^\(EMAIL\|STREET\)=` will avoid to touch lines like `USER_EMAIL=...` or `SOME_STREET=`

Comment: Unfortunately `sed '/^\(EMAIL\|STREET\)=/d' file` isn't working for me.

Comment: @alphanumeric it was tested with gnu sed. And it is simple BRE, should work.